# Render from Bean to UI have issue to show Double space

Tags: java, xhtml, javabeans, render

My problem is I have One mybean.java and one my.xhtml page where I am taking dynamic input from user name storing the name of customer in Bean.
And after stoing I am accessing name and showing on userinterface.

Here is code

```
<h:form id="NamemyForm1">

  <h:outputLabel value="Name" />           
  <h:inputText id="name1" value="#{myBean.firstName}">
  </h:inputText>


 <h:commandButton render="validation" id="submit" type="submit" action="my.jsf" value="Submit" />


 <h:outputText value="#{myBean.firstName}"/>

 </h:form>
```

Here is Bean class
myBean.java

```
public class myBean {
 private String firstName = null;

 public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
    }

 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
          this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

But the problem is when I am stoing value "HI_I_am__Ankit_____saxena" on Ui its showing ""HI_I_am_Ankit_saxena" (not showing double space only showing single space)

NOTE: In storing it is actually storing double space in bean but only UI its not showing with actual one.

Please help me
Thanks In advance

Comment: This is the standard behaviour of XHTML elements. To change it, set the `white-space` property of the outputtext element to `pre` or `pre-wrap`.

Comment: Where I need to set this white-space property

Comment: Does the outputText element have a class or an id?

Comment: No ,but if we required we can use it but issue should be solve.

Comment: And One more point I think  for fix this it requires any xml parser but I dont know the actual name of parser like I am using richfaces than richface xml parser